# What's the point of rejecting a cookie?

Tags: cookies

When you access a website, lynx provide the option to reject a cookie, what's the point of doing so?

All I thought about is that if you don't accept a cookie, you cookie won't be stolen during a XSS attack, is that everything?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cookies can be used to keep you logged in to a website, track your browsing history, log your activity and preferences on a website, and some other things. Rejecting cookies prevents this information from being tracked and easily available to the site owner or third-party affiliates. It will also, of course, prevent attackers from accessing or abusing the data through a number of means such as XSS, CRSF, DNS cache poisoning, traffic sniffing, local system exploitation, etc.

I suggest you read more about [HTTP Cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) on Wikipedia, and search the web for further details as well. The following sections of the Wiki entry will probably be of particular interest to you:

- [Uses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Uses)
- [Privacy and third-party cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Privacy_and_third-party_cookies)
- [Cookie theft and session hijacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Cookie_theft_and_session_hijacking)

There are some down-sides to rejecting some cookies.

- Your authentication to a website will not persist across sessions - you will have to log in again every visit.
- Your preferences on a website may not be saved, or may not be available until you login.
- You may not be able to use a shopping cart on e-commerce websites.
- Other site features that rely on cookies will not function.

Just like any security measure, the choice of allowing or rejecting cookies for any site, or for third-party hosts, comes down to how you want to balance security vs. usability.